# Meteor mongo get and set value

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am pretty new to Meteor and I'm just toying around to explore it at the moment. 
I've got stuck with an issue trying to get and set a value in the mongo database, named Persons.
The MongoDB is named Persons and I've inserted two objects: 
        {name: "abcdef", coming: "false"}

If the user changes the state of a checkbox, that's attached to a name, a function is called that should find the value of the boolean coming.
What I think I got right so far, is that I can set the value like this?

```
    var id = this._id;
    Persons.update({_id: id}, {$set: {coming: true}});
```

But how can i get the value and make comparisons with it?

Comment: in what context? Can't you just use `Persons.findOne(id)`?

Comment: But that's just results in an object, how can i get the name and coming variables when I have the object? Like in java where I'd write obj Persons.findOne(id) and to get the boolean value boolVal = obj.coming

Comment: the exact same: `var obj = Persons.findOne(id); obj.coming`. By the way, this is just a javascript question. You may want to read a quick tutorial to javascript and JSON.

Comment: Oh super, i worked! Many thanks for your help, I'll follow your advice regarding the javascript.

Comment: i've added it as an answer just so the question doesn't appear unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In meteor you use `.find(selector).fetch()` or `.findOne(selector)` on collections to get objects, where `selector` is a usual mongodb selector or just an id (string). After that you can pick out any fields using the usual `.` syntax of javascript.

Example:

```
var obj = Persons.findOne(id);
if (obj) { // the given id was found
   console.log(obj.coming);
}
```